# Hide soft keyboard in android after using library

Tags: android, search, android-softkeyboard

I cant hide soft keyboard from my code. I`m using some menthods:

1. in java code:

   ```
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
   ```
2. in manifest:

   ```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
   ```

this dont work for me. Can you help me?

P.S: Its happend when I use this library https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method from Activity where you want to hide soft keyboard (you can put it in to diffetent class & call using class name as its static)

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null)
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity
                    .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```